# Jetty slow startup... hibernate issue?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jetty

I'm running Jetty 8 with Eclipse. After a Java update this morning, JettyLauncher is now taking 6 minutes to start up, as opposed to 10 seconds before. Several of the delays seem to deal with Hibernate (I don't remember seeing too much about Hibernate when Jetty was running at a normal speed). Could anyone confirm or deny that hibernate is causing an issue with the JettyLauncher? Or otherwise pinpoint where this delay is coming from?

The Jetty launch delays the most during these lines in the console output:

5347 [main] INFO org.hibernate.validator.util.Version - Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
...
74022 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
starting guide stats cache service

97089 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/properties/build.properties]

118670 [main] INFO org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@16bc6df1] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
CacheReportsJob.cacheGuideStats()

119649 [main] INFO org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 119133 ms

119661 [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/C:/Users/MBeatty/Documents/Tortoise%20SVN/Beek%20Checkout%20v2/trunk/server/}
Oct 17, 2013 11:54:22 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized

INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.3 (FCS b02) for context ''
Oct 17, 2013 11:54:59 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance

INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Oct 17, 2013 11:55:43 AM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent

INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 3.2-SNAPSHOT
Oct 17, 2013 11:55:43 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ELResolverInitPhaseListener populateFacesELResolverForJsp

INFO: JSF1027: [null] The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with the JSP container.